# How to point a domain without changing name servers

Tags: web, dns, subdomain

My client has a website at exampleA.com, but want their new domain name exampleB.com to point to the server that hosts exampleA.com.

They have certain emails setup with exampleB.com...so I want to avoid changing the name servers, in case I mess with these settings (I don't know all the info yet).

If I simply want exampleB.com to point to a different server, what DNS records should I change? I have a static IP for the server.

[image]

Is it just the A record I need to modify? I'm not good with this DNS malarkey.

Thanks for your help.
Mikey.

Comment: One small comment when changing DNS values don't forget it could take up to 24 hours to see change!

Comment: @LeroyMeijer Yep, I'm aware of this, thanks! Any idea as to what I need to do though? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just update the **A** record. You may have to update the web server config file on exampleA.com server to listen and serve the requests for exampleB.com.

If the static IP address you have is in IPv6 format then you would have to update the **AAAA** DNS record.

Comment: But keep in mind that if the mail is sent to an other server you need to keep this in mind. This is a config of a domain of mine: http://s9.postimg.org/rqw244fi7/dns.png

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by changing A record in the domain account will solve the problem. In this case, you do not need to change the nameserver in the domain account